# IDE NetBeans в Ubuntu

Tags: c++, netbeans, ubuntu

Хочу скомпилировать хелло ворлд, но выдает ошибку

> /usr/bin/make" -f
> nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=
> SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf make[1]: Вход
> в каталог
> `/home/alex/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1'
> "/usr/bin/make"  -f
> nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk
> dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/welcome_1
> make[2]: Вход в каталог`/home/alex/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1'
> mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86 rm
> -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/newfile.o.d"
> g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF
> "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/newfile.o.d"
> -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/newfile.o newfile.cpp mkdir -p
> dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86 g++     -o
> dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/welcome_1
> build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/newfile.o
> build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/welcome.o 
> build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/welcome.o:
> In function `main':
> /home/alex/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1/welcome.cc:33:
> multiple definition of`main'
> build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/newfile.o:/home/alex/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1/newfile.cpp:3:
> first defined here collect2: error: ld
> returned 1 exit status make[2]: 
> ***[dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/welcome_1]
> Ошибка 1 make[2]: Выход из каталога
> `/home/alex/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1'
> make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Ошибка 2
> make[1]: Выход из каталога`/home/alex/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1'
> make:***  [.build-impl] Ошибка 2
>
> СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 273ms)

Comment: @neko69, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тексту, который Вы прикрепили, у Вас определены 2 или более функций с названием **main**.

Более ничего добавить не могу, к сожалению, без кода программы и других данных.